# Calcular intervalor de datas em meses ( Lista de Datas )

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

Tenho uma Lista de Datas

01.01.2017
   intervalo de 13 meses
02.02.2018
   intervalor de 14 meses 
03.04.2019
   intervalor de 8 meses 
19.12.2019

Existe alguma forma de fazer um select que retorna os meses entre as datas listadas
Ja achei algumas respostas aqui no forum mais o exemplo deles é sempre entre duas datas nao o intervalor de varias datas listadas

A pergunta é para saber se tem como resolver com um Select..  senão teremos que desenvolver uma função para essa finalidade...

Obrigado

Comment: No PostgreSQL você pode utilizar a função `age`. Do resultado (um interval) extraia o ano, multiplique por 12, e some aos meses também extraído. Se quiser determinar a nova data acrescentando um intervalo é só somar/subtrair o `interval` à data original.

Comment: Não é bem isso que eu quero...   ele mostra a diferença do registro lista com a data de hoje...  eu quero a diferença entre os registros.. listados..  ou entendi errado ??

Comment: Utilize a função `age` com dois parâmetros: o timestamp de início e o timestamp de fim.